# Conditional image galleries in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to make a box with 3 options (2013, 2005, 2004) that are all hyperlinked to their own seperate jquery slider image galleries. I want it so that say when you click 2013, the 2013 image gallery appears and then when you click 2005, the 2005 image gallery appears instead.

I dont know if i should be using 'click event listeners' or just using html. I am new to coding and would appreciate as much help. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could just link to those pages and have the same navigation on each page. Or create an iFrame (with a name/id) and use that as the target of your links and load the galleries into it from your main page.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7yMG/1/)

If you are using a thirdy part plugin to provide gallery functionality you can solve your problem this way:

create a second container box, and put the 3 different galleries into the container, but hidden.

example:

```
<div class="select-gallery">
 <ul>
  <li data="gallery1">2013</li> <!-- the data attribute links the list element to it's related gallery -->
  <li data="gallery2">2005</li>
  <li data="gallery3">2004</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery-container">
 <ul id="gallery1" class="is-hidden gallery">[...]</ul>
 <ul id="gallery2" class="is-hidden gallery">[...]</ul>
 <ul id="gallery3" class="is-hidden gallery">[...]</ul>
</div>
```

Then with javascript, (i'm assuming you are going to use jquery to speed up)
[jQuery Framework](http://jquery.com/), you can attach an event handler to the click event of the select-gallery list elements to show any of your galleries, this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select-gallery").on("click", "li", function () {
        var $data = $(this).attr("data");
        $(".gallery").css("display", "none");
        $("#" + $data).fadeIn();
    });
});
```